# How do I add a subtree with recursive submodules?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I added a Git subtree to an existing repository:

```
$ git subtree add --prefix etc/theos https://github.com/theos/theos.git master --squash
```

But, this repository is usually cloned with the `--recursive` flag and I'm noticing that some stuff in the repository that should be there isn't. I didn't see a `--recursive` flag for subtree.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422693/