# How do I init submodules nested in a subtree?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

Apparently, adding a subtree of a repository that has submodules will break `git submodule init`. Here is a script which reproduces the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

mkdir submod
cd submod
git init
touch foo
git add foo
git commit -asm "This is a submodule"
cd ..

mkdir subtree
cd subtree
git init
git submodule add `realpath ../submod` submod
git commit -asm "This has reference to submodule"
cd ..

mkdir top
cd top
git init
touch bar
git add bar
git commit -asm "Dummy commit so HEAD resolves correctly"
git subtree add --prefix=subtree `realpath ../subtree` master

# This fails!
git submodule init
```

What this script is doing is:

1. Create a repo submod
2. Create a repo subtree that has a submodule reference to submod
3. Create a repo top that has a subtree reference to subtree

Upon further consideration, it is clear what the problem is: the subtree mechanism has added subtree's submodule reference to submod to the tree, but the `.gitmodules` metadata remains in `subtree/.gitmodules`, not the top-level `.gitmodules`, which means that `git submodule init` fails. If we copy the contents of `subtree/.gitmodules` to `.gitmodules`, adjusting all the paths accordingly, that solves the problem...

```
[submodule "submod"]
    path = subtree/submod
    url = /Users/ezyang/Dev/labs/git-subtree-submod/submod
```

...but it is a bit of pain if the subtree has a lot of submodules. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the exact same situation :)

Comment: We stopped using subtrees lol

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell reading the docs and source code... Git subtree is *completely* separate from Git submodules and will not actively manage any submodules that may be contained within the subtree project itself.

As you found out, `.gitmodules`, which is critical to the function of `git submodule init`, needs to be maintained in the root of the "main" repository (for lack of a better term).

> Upon further consideration, it is clear what the problem is: the
> subtree mechanism has added subtree's submodule reference to submod to
> the tree, but the .gitmodules metadata remains in subtree/.gitmodules,
> not the top-level .gitmodules, which means that git submodule init
> fails. If we copy the contents of subtree/.gitmodules to .gitmodules,
> adjusting all the paths accordingly, that solves the problem...

I strongly recommend not mixing these features.

Comment: You _might_ be able to cobble together a solution for copying the subtree .gitsubmodules into the main repository with the subtree merge strategy (not the subcommand) and filter-branch... but that seems like a nightmare. Also, you wouldn't be able to merge multiple subtree .gitsubmodules.

Comment: Honestly, I copied the `.gitmodules` file from the subtree root to the root repo root and edited the name of the submodule and path and it works just fine. I don't see what all the fuss is about.